# Case-insensitive Func

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I have a `Func<Message, bool>` where `Message` is a class of mine.

I build up a `Lambda` and compile it into a `Func<Message,bool>`

```
public static Func<Classes.Message, bool> GetPredicate(string expression)
{
    Func<Classes.Message, bool> result = null;

    try
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Classes.Message), "Message");
        var lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { parameter }, null, expression);
        result = lambda.Compile() as Func<Classes.Message, bool>;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Fatal(e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This results in

```
Message => (((Message.ContainsProperty("Gender") == True) AndAlso (Message.GetPropertyValue("Gender") != "Female")) AndAlso (Message.ChannelString != "FacebookComment"))
```

Later on, the `Func` gets executed but I'd like to make it case-insensitve so when a Message objet gets passed in but the gender is "female" not "Female" it still returns a true in the bool.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: So, you're creating `expression` yourself?

Comment: What is the string that comes in? As ispiro says in his answer the property could have ToUpper() applied, or you could do a `string.compare` instead (assuming the lambda parser supports that).

Comment: Would that not mean making the incoming Message properties all uppercase?

Comment: No, your expression would contain something like `Message.ToUpper() == "FEMALE"`. You're doing it as part of the lambda when checking the property, not setting the property itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ToUpper()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
Message.GetPropertyValue("Gender").ToUpper() != "FEMALE"
```

Answer (score 0):

That's being generated from the expression.

I'm fairly certain that the static public methods on string are exposed via DynamicQuery, so you would need to you string.compare:

```
(x) => String.Compare (x.Gender, "Female", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Unfortunately this would mean that you can't use the sql-like syntax, but it should parse and run.